# Are there any hierarchical, multi select controls that use check boxes in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to be able to select multiple options on a web form, but those options are hierarchical.  For example:

```
Option 1
  Option 1 a
  Option 1 b
Option 2
```

The user should be able to select Option 1, or Option 1a, etc.  Selecting Option 1 a should automatically select Option 1.

Any controls/solutions out there that fit the bill?  (I'm not looking to spend $)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article, which explains how you can accomplish this with a normal TreeView control.

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/ASPNET-TreeView-and-Checkboxes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ComponentOne has this support built into their ASP.NET AJAX TreeView control. Another nice feature is the **built-in drag and drop nodes**. I would recommend looking at the [checkable treeview](http://demo.componentone.com/aspnet/controlexplorer/C1TreeView/VisualStyles.aspx) demo here.

This can also be done with a standard ASP.NET TreeView and setting ShowCheckBoxes="all" like so.

```
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All">
    </asp:TreeView>
```